# Get Row and Column number from "ThisComponent.CurrentSelection" in libreoffice calc basic

Tags: libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-calc

I have this code where I can get which one is the current selected cell and use it to modify its value:

```
theSelection = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection
theSelection.setString("some value")
```

Now I want to move to the next column to the right, if it was Microsoft excel VBA I could just use something like `theSelection.Offset(0,1)` but that's not the case. So I'm doing some workarounds of course:

```
nextCell = oActiveSheet.getCellByPosition( ???currentColumn + 1, ???currentRow)
ThisComponent.CurrentController.select( nextCell )
```

I just want to know the simplest way to replace these `???` to the actual values of the `theSelection` var to move to the next column to the right.

I also tried this:

```
nextCell = oActiveSheet.getCellByPosition( column() + 1, row())
```

But I don't know why it is always returning `column() = 1` and `row() = 1` in regardless of which is the value of the `CurrentSelection`. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/250774/get-row-and-column-number-from-thiscomponentcurrentselection/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the cell address.

```vb
Sub ChangeAndThenGoToCellToRightOfSelection
    oActiveSheet = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getActiveSheet()
    oSels = ThisComponent.getCurrentSelection()
    If oSels.supportsService("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCell") Then
        'A single cell is selected.
        oSels.setString("some value")
        address = oSels.getCellAddress()
        nextCell = oActiveSheet.getCellByPosition(address.Column + 1, address.Row)
        ThisComponent.CurrentController.select(nextCell)
    End If
End Sub
```

To see what an object can do, use an introspection tool such as XrayTool or MRI.