# libreoffice calc Macro to shift focused cell to the right by one cell

Tags: macros, cell, libreoffice, calc

I have a cell in focus. I want to shift the focus to one cell immediately in the right using a macro.
I've tried this but to no avail...

```
Sub move_cursor

sheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    cell = sheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")

    cursor = sheet.createCursorByRange(cell)
    MsgBox cursor.ImplementationName

'    Move to next cell
cursor.gotoNext()

' Trying to shift using offset to next cell on right.
cursor.gotoOffset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: By "cell in focus", do you mean the [**active cell**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-get-current-cell-column-row-in-basic/54498/2?u=johnsun)? And  "to shift the focus" do you mean "select the cell" as shown in [**Listing 6.14: Select a single cell so it has an outline**](https://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a LibreOffice BASIC macro that works (I'm on LO 7.6) from Jim K. [Get Row and Column number from "ThisComponent.CurrentSelection" in libreoffice calc basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419076/get-row-and-column-number-from-thiscomponent-currentselection-in-libreoffice-c)

But it's great that this page gives a number of  diverse methods as offered by JohnSUN

Comment: Please take into account that the code you link to in your answer only works under certain conditions. If more than one cell is selected when the macro runs, or if `ThisComponent.getCurrentSelection()` refers to an object on the worksheet (such as an image or control), then the macro will not do anything. This is exactly what the comment “A single cell is selected” says.

Answer (score 0):

Is moving the cursor to the right one cell the same as pressing the right arrow? Then the easiest way to create the desired script is to enable macro recording, press the right arrow, stop macro recording, give the macro a meaningful name. The result will be code similar to this

```
sub moveCursorRight
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "By"
args1(0).Value = 1
args1(1).Name = "Sel"
args1(1).Value = false

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoRight", "", 0, args1())
end sub
```

This will really get the job done.

Using the code snippets from my first comment, the macro code could be like this:

```
Sub jumpOneCellToRight
Dim nRow As Long, nColumn As Long, oSheet As Variant, oController As Variant 
    nRow = ActiveCell(2)
    nColumn = ActiveCell(1)
    oController = ThisComponent.getCurrentController()
    oSheet = oController.getActiveSheet()
    oController.Select(oSheet.getCellByPosition(nColumn+1,nRow))
    oController.Select(ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCellRanges"))
End Sub
```

Using [**VBA compatibility**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03103350.html?DbPAR=BASIC#bm_id3145090) this can be written more shorter

```
Option VbaSupport 1

Sub goRight()
     Selection.Offset(0,1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the dispatcher  {as for some reason I still can't understand} It is involved - somehow - with the non-directed re-positioning of my cells, and the results of which are be quite serious, hence I was looking for a way to 'hand-code' it.
Do you know of any such solutions by say using the code above which is in the official LO literature.

Comment: Added a script using the API to the answer

Comment: Tq JohnSUN. I was OK with VBA but in moving to LO/OpenSource I wanted to be good in native LO BASIC - even suspending my python development in LO to do so - {although I predict python to program LO will dominate in a few years} So I'm also reluctant to "VBA" things in LO. If my  current strategy of ASCII conversion to coordinates and using that to jump to another cell proves too unwieldy then at least I have the two much appreciated alternatives that you've provided here. Thank you - I'm really thankful for your help.

Comment: JohnSUN,
In your Sub jumpOneCellToRight,
you have     nRow = ActiveCell(2)
    nColumn = ActiveCell(1)
What are the 2 and 1 arguments for? LO doesn't accept them.

Comment: @Micklos [**ActiveCell()**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-get-current-cell-column-row-in-basic/54498/2?u=johnsun) is a BASIC function that most accurately identifies the cell in the spreadsheet, the only cell that is currently surrounded by a bold border. Unlike other methods (for example, using CurrentSelection), this code is not subject to errors. The version I'm referring to has three optional parameters - the first of which is the **resultType**: 1 - return column number (based 0), 2 - return row number. For details, see the comments in the function code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on JohnSUN's (TQ) answer,
I changed things a bit and now it works for me...

```
Sub BetterCloseDataEntry_jumpOneCellToRight

Dim nRow As Long, nColumn As Long, oSheet As Variant, oController As Variant 

    nColumn = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getSelection().RangeAddress.StartColumn
    nRow = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getSelection().RangeAddress.StartRow

    oController = ThisComponent.getCurrentController()
    oSheet = oController.getActiveSheet()
    oController.Select(oSheet.getCellByPosition(nColumn+1,nRow))
    oController.Select(ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCellRanges"))
End Sub
```

Avoiding any possible error from the method based around the Jim K solution (link to it is on this thread) featuring the line

```
If oSels.supportsService("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCell")
```